# Relativity equations

Tags: spacetime, reference-frames, time, relativity, inertial-frames

In the equations for time dilation and length contraction, what is a good way of choosing who is the relative time and length and who is the proper time and length so we can get good measurements of the variables? Should the proper time and length be the static observer $t$ and $l$ and the moving observer $t'$ and $l'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is kind of the whole point behind the [principle of relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_relativity): there's no real definition of "static" as opposed to "moving".  Instead, you simply pick one observer and — if you want — call that one static, and any other one moving.

The key requirement is that you should get the same *physical* results no matter what you pick.  It's true that you'll get different numbers for certain things.  For example, the velocity — if you swap the special "static" observer, the velocity of the "moving" observer will flip sign.  But you've also changed the observer whose motion you're measuring, so why shouldn't it change?  On the other hand, the principle of relativity tells us that we must get the same answer about certain things like whether or not two objects collide.

As for measuring time dilation and length contraction, again, any choice you make for the static frame is a valid choice — but when you give the numbers, you have to specify which frame they're being measured in.

Comment: Ok nice ! I think I understand, it's just weird the results always change and seems counterintuitive to the fact you should only get one good answer so it becomes confusing which is the answer you should stick to.

Comment: Yep, it's weird.  But you get used to it.  Just remember: You can stick to whichever one you want, as long as you say which one you're sticking to.